# Bluetooth socket, write and read strings

Tags: android, bluetooth

How can I output and read strings over a bluetooth socket. Right now it prints the value of the bytes being sent which is the number of character 0-255. So 'hi' would be 2, 'bye' would be 3. Here is my read and write functions:

```
public void read() {
            byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
            final int bytes;

            try {
                bytes = iStream.read(buffer);

                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        updateTView(bytes);
                    }
                });
                Log.i("WTF",String.valueOf(bytes));
            } catch(IOException e) {
                //TODO: something
            }
}

public void writeText(byte bytes[]) {
    try {
        oStream.write(bytes);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        //TODO: something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                  private InputStream input;
```

Perform this in background thread.

```
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                  bytes = input.read(buffer);
                  String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                  // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                  System.out.println(readMessage);
```